# Sorting of Array Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of type `[Int:Float]`. The `Int` is my ID, while `Float` is my actual data. Example:

`[12: 0.31, 8: 0.01, 10: 0.02, 14: 0.025, 9: 0.015, 15: 0.025, 11: 0.02, 13: 0.02]`

My problem here is how to sort my ID, which is `Int` in ascending order. Meaning the result should be as follows:

`[8: 0.01, 9: 0.015, 10: 0.02, 11: 0.02, 12: 0.31, 13: 0.02, 14: 0.025, 15: 0.025,]`

Comment: that's no array. that is a dictionary.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Dictionary_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:VSs10Dictionary: [A Dictionary is ..]  a collection of key-value pairs **with no defined ordering**.

Answer (score 1):

```
let dictionary = [12: 0.31, 8: 0.01, 10: 0.02, 14: 0.025, 9: 0.015, 15: 0.025, 11: 0.02, 13: 0.02]
let sortedArray = dictionary.sort{$0.0 < $1.0}

print(sortedArray)  // [(8, 0.01), (9, 0.015), (10, 0.02), (11, 0.02), (12, 0.31), (13, 0.02), (14, 0.025), (15, 0.025)]\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you sort you array in Swift. It's working great!

```
// Sort array values in descending order
var a = [6,3,2,1,5,4]
a = a.sort { $0 > $1 }
print(a)

// Sort array values in ascending order
var a = [6,3,2,1,5,4]/
a = a.sort { $0 < $1 }
print(a)
```